# WPF C# Checkbox IsChecked binding inside an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Well, I have an ItemsControl bound to an array of booleans. Items are just CheckBoxes:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding A, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the VM there's a bool array which the ItemsControl is bound to:

```cs
private bool[] a = new bool[5] { true, true, false, true, false };
public bool[] A
{
    get => a;
    set => SetProperty(ref a, value);
}
```

(The SetProperty function sets new value and raises the OnPropertyChanged)

So when I run the program I can see that the ItemsControl gets values properly, but it doesn't set any of them after CheckBoxes are clicked. Works like if I'd set the binding mode to OneWay. Why?

Thanks in advance, and I hope the question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: That won't work. You have to bind the ItemsSource to a collection of objects with a boolean property, not a collection of bools.

Comment: @Clemens that sounds like an answer but do I really need to create another empty class with the only bool property inside?

Comment: Yes. The item class would have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the bool property setter would have to fire the PropertyChanged event. The collection property that the ItemsSource is bound to might however be readonly, e.g. like `public ObservableCollection<BoolWrapper> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<BoolWrapper>();`

Comment: You can make it working if you add command to checkbox. In command handler you can change corresponding item in array and rise notificaiton for a complete property. Not optimal, but another possibility. The difficulty would be to pass index.

Comment: @Clemens I've just tried and it really worked for me. Thank you very much for the nice and quick answer!